# How to I keep the original file datetimes while using Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is the an option that I could specify to mercurial in order to convince it to use the original timestamp of the files instead of the local time of the update?

When I make a clone I do want to have identical files (same timestamps) on any two machines.

Note: I am not looking for `archive` option, I want fully working copies.

Answer (score 5):

I've not used either of them, but it sounds like you wants something like this:

- [Timestmp Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TimestampExtension)
- [TimestampMod Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TimestampModExtension)

Comment: ****, I was hopping for a solution that does not require a plugin.

Comment: Yeah, sorry,  you could mock it up w/ a commit hook and an update hook, but it would have to be done on each system, wouldn't work as well, and would eventually grow into an extension. :)